# Is there a way to disambiguate location parameter values for google maps embed API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-embed

For example, the URL:

https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/M25

shows the postcode area in Manchester (which is what I am after), whereas the following URL for an embedded map:

https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=M25 ..etc..

shows the M25 motorway.

Is there a way to get the embedded map to treat the value of  as a postcode outward code in the same way as with the first URL?  My application has only the postcode available, so I couldn't use q=Manchester+M25 (which works) without doing an additional lookup.

Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

adding "postcode" to the query string works for me (i.e.`q=postcode+M25`):

http://www.geocodezip.com/example_embedded_map_address_postcode.html

```
<iframe width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" 
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=postcode+M25&key=MY_API_KEY" 
  allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[image: screen shot of embedded map]